# mongodb make dynamic query for sort field options

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using aggregate query for showing some results given some code snippets

```
if (name) {
  sort = { '$sort': { name: -1 } }
} else {
  sort = ''
}

User.aggregate([sort, { $match: {} }])
```

Problem is when value of name is not set aggregate query is giving error how to make this aggregate query dynamic in nodejs. I need to fit sort option anywhere depending on filter select by user.

Answer (score 2):

this should work :

```
var query = [{
    $match:   {}    
}]

if(name)
{
    query.unshift({ '$sort': { name: -1 } });
}

User.aggregate(query)
```

Comment: I cant do this because I have aggregate pipeline i need to fit sort option anywhere , query.push will push sort option in end.

Comment: Instead of push use [**`unshift`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to add the sort pipeline at the beginning of the array `if(name)
{
    query.unshift({ '$sort': { name: -1 } });
}`

Comment: It will not also work, sometimes i need to put sort in beginning sometimes end.